# Align button text if image is present

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a button which I'm using multiple times in my webpage. The buttons styles will be as

1. Button with Text and Image.
2. Button with only Image.
3. Button with only Text.

As shown in the `fiddle`
http://jsfiddle.net/xzBaZ/4/

I'm using he same css for the button class. I need to align the Text Vertically to center if it is the first case. and no extra alignment is required for other cases.

How can I do this??

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xzBaZ/5/

Comment: ya. Thanks. How did you do that? I tried but in vain

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom` on the `img` or make the image and the text equal line heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: bottom` on the `<img>` or make the image and the text equal line heights.  The latter requires you to know the image height beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You should Write the text in span

```
  <button onclick="return false" class="super button"><span>Awesome Button &raquo;
           </span> <img src="/Buttons5/add-to-cart-light.png" alt="" width="28" height="20"/>
```

and also specify the css for span

```
.button span{
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
}
```